# access NSDictionary content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary like

```
{
        nodeAttributeArray =         (
                        {
                attributeName = ReportDate;
                nodeContent = "08-31-1986";
            },
                        {
                attributeName = ReportType;
                nodeContent = PQ1;
            }
        );
        nodeName = Period;
    },
    {
        nodeAttributeArray =         (
                        {
                attributeName = ReportDate;
                nodeContent = "08-31-1987";
            },
                        {
                attributeName = ReportType;
                nodeContent = PQ2;
            }
        );
        nodeName = Period;
    }
```

I have shown 2 values here. But there are almost 50 such members inside my dict
How do I access the contents of this inside a for loop ?

I want the value inside "nodeContent"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the data structure, it seems to me that the root structure is a List and not a dictionary as you pose in the question. Is that correct? If that is the case, then an iteration for printing the attribute values to the console would be:

```
NSArray *array; // this is your list with 50 values or so in it
//... some code to load the data into array
NSDictionary *d;
for (NSDictionary *period in array){
    NSLog(@"%@",[period objectForKey:@"nodeName"]);
    for (NSDictionary *nodeAttributeArray in [period objectForKey:@"nodeAttributeArray"]){
        NSLog(@"\t%@=%@",[nodeAttributeArray objectForKey:@"attributeName"],[nodeAttributeArray objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am not very sure..But this gets returned by an XML parser, which says the return type is an NSDictionary...(http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html)

I just debugged this in console and it said;
Printing description of replist_rptdt_dict:
(
        {
        nodeAttributeArray =         (
                        {
                attributeName = ReportDate;
......

Comment: It says "Each result in the array of nodes returned will be an NSDictionary with the following structure:"

Comment: In the usual notation if the printed data structure starts with '(' then it is a list. Check out the runtime type with a NSLog(@"%@",[obj class]);

Comment: It says "__NSArrayM" for obj class

Comment: I am a bit confused, as in the .h file I have set it as dict. 
NSMutableDictionary *replist_rptdt_dict;

Comment: Objective-C is a highly dynamic language. Therefore, keeping the declared types matching the runtime types is the programmer's job. You can do NSDictionary *d = [NSArray array]; and all you get is a warning. d will be an array, no matter what the declared static type is. There is clearly a type mismatch in your code. Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: ok..let me just check and I'll get back to you. Thanks again for all your help.